# What does this handwritten phrase mean? (Characters identified: 见有广告的他特别高兴)

Tags: meaning, writing

What does this sentence mean in this hand writing?

[image]

Comment: 见(?)有(?)广(?)先(?)的他特别高兴. More context will be helpful for recognition.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about recognization of someone's hand-writing.

Answer (score 3):

It was ”见有广告的他特别高兴“, when seeing the commercials, he is especially happy.

Comment: Don't you have any more context? That character doesn't look like 告.

Comment: Yes, I do. 广告 was mentioned earlier . I know sometimes scripts could be confusing...

Comment: Doctors' handwriting haha.